# Tikz scale key not scaling coordinates properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have created an image using tikz, but when scaling its size it is not coverting the coordinates appropiately, as you can see in the image below. I think its owing to using a lot of nodes to draw the images, particularly the orange and cyan lines, which are also the two that are not being scaled.

[image: Scaling in Tikz]

I am quite baffled right now, as other very similar images that I have created do scale properly. I know that I could use things such as `resizebox`, but I do not want the text to be scaled. I would really appreciate any help :)

A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Loads a bunch of packages
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{help lines}=[thin,gray!40]
%- Define colors to be used 
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}%             
\definecolor{Cyan}{rgb}{0.0, 0.72, 0.92}%  
\definecolor{Orange}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}%   
%
\begin{document}
%

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %- Axis node
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (Origin Ax2) {};
        %- Axis
    \begin{scope}[-stealth,very thick]
        \draw (Origin Ax2)  -- +(0,3.5) node[anchor=south east,rotate=90] {Y axis}; % Y-axis
        \draw (Origin Ax2) -- +(4.75,0) node[anchor = north east]{X axis}; % X axis
    \end{scope}

    %- Blue line starting node
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=0.25 of Origin Ax2] (Blue Begins) {};
    %- Blue line
    \begin{scope}[color=Blue,very thick]
        \draw (Blue Begins) -- ++(0,3) node[anchor=north west]{Blue}  -- ++(3.5,0) -- ++(0,-3);
    \end{scope}

    %- Nodes to guide left and right side of the parabolas <- I think the problem might be here (?)
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,above=1.25 of Blue Begins] (Cyan left anchor) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=3.5 of Cyan left anchor] (Cyan right anchor) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,above=0.5 of Blue Begins] (Orange left anchor) {};
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=3.5 of Orange left anchor] (Orange right anchor) {};
    
    %- A label
    \node[below right= 0 and 1.5 of Blue Begins] (A) {A};
    \node[above=2.25 of A] (A top) {}; % Maximum of paraboles
    \begin{scope}[ dashed] % Line from (A) to (A top), but it appears waaay higher so modified by hand
        \draw (A) -- ++(0,2.8);
    \end{scope}
    
    %- Cyan line
    \begin{scope}[very thick, color=Cyan]
        \draw (A top) parabola ++(-1,-1) -- (Cyan left anchor); %Left side
        \draw  (A top) parabola ++(1,-1) node(DeltaAux){} -- (Cyan right anchor) node[anchor=north east]{Cyan}; % Right side
    \end{scope}
    
    %- Orange line
    \begin{scope}[very thick, color=Orange]
        \draw (A top) parabola ++(-0.5,-1.75) -- (Orange left anchor);
        \draw  (A top) parabola ++(0.5,-1.75) -- (Orange right anchor) node[anchor=north east]{Orange};
    \end{scope}
    
    %- Delta
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[dashed] (A top) -- +(2,0) node(DeltaTop){};
        \draw[dashed] (DeltaAux) -- +(1,0) node(DeltaBottom){};
        \draw[<->] (DeltaBottom) -- (DeltaTop) node[rotate = 90,midway, below]{$\Delta$};           
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: just add `transform shape` after scale:  `\begin {tikzpicture} [scale = 2, transform shape]`  ..., nodes ignore scaling without that declaration.

Comment: Transform shape also scales text, which is something that I would rather prevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found how to do it. As J Leon V said, nodes are not rescaled unless the key `transform shape` is used, but this also rescales the text. However, this **only** affects nodes declared with `\node`, but **not** nodes that are declared in the middle of a path/line. So, I modified the code so I declare the nodes that I need at the same time that I am creating the lines on the image.

It works properly now. Everything is scaled but the text remains where it should be, and with the size it should. I am posting the modification below, so it might serve as reference for other people :)

```
\documentclass[IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Loads a bunch of packages
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzstyle{help lines}=[thin,gray!40]
%- Define colors to be used 
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}%           
\definecolor{Cyan}{rgb}{0.0, 0.72, 0.92}%  
\definecolor{Orange}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}%    
\begin{document}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, on grid]
    %- Axis node
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (Origin Ax2) {};

    %- Blue line
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=0.25 of Origin Ax2] (Blue Begins) {}; %Origin node of blue rectangle
    %- Blue line + A node
    \begin{scope}[color=Blue,very thick]
        \draw (Blue Begins) -- ++(0,3) node[anchor=north west]{Blue}  -- ++(3.5,0) -- ++(0,-3) --++ (-3.5,0) node[below, midway] (A){ \color{black} A};
    \end{scope}
    %- Dashed line from A to top
    \begin{scope}[ dashed] % Line from (A) to (A top)
            \draw (A) -- ++(0,2.8) node[below,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (A top) {};
    \end{scope}

    %- Axis
    \begin{scope}[-stealth,very thick]
        \draw (Origin Ax2)  -- +(0,3.5) node[anchor=south east,rotate=90] {Y axis}; % Y-axis
        \draw (Origin Ax2) -- +(4.75,0) node[anchor = north east]{X axis}; % X axis
    \end{scope}

%   %- Nodes to guide left and right side of the parabolas <- I think the problem might be here (?)
%   \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,above=1.25 of Blue Begins] (Cyan left anchor) {};
%   \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=3.5 of Cyan left anchor] (Cyan right anchor) {};
%   \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,above=0.5 of Blue Begins] (Orange left anchor) {};
%   \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0,right=3.5 of Orange left anchor] (Orange right anchor) {};

    %- Cyan line
    \begin{scope}[very thick, color=Cyan]
        \draw (A top) parabola ++(-1,-1) -- ++(-0.75,0); %Left side
        \draw  (A top) parabola ++(1,-1) node(Cyan){} -- ++(0.75,0) node[midway,below]{Cyan}; % Right side
    \end{scope}

    %- Orange line
    \begin{scope}[very thick, color=Orange]
        \draw (A top) parabola ++(-0.5,-1.75) -- ++(-1.25,-0.5);
        \draw  (A top) parabola ++(0.5,-1.75) -- ++(1.25,-0.5) node[midway, below]{Orange};
    \end{scope}

    %- Delta
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[dashed] (A top) -- +(2,0) node(DeltaTop){};
        \draw[dashed] (Cyan) -- +(1,0) node(DeltaBottom){};
        \draw[<->] (DeltaBottom) -- (DeltaTop) node[rotate = 90,midway, below]{$\Delta$};           
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```